# cPanel on new host doesn't have cpanel.example.com and webmail.example.com like the old host did

Tags: web-hosting, dns, cpanel, shared-hosting, webmail

Previously I had a cPanel **shared hosting** plan where I could login to cPanel admin area using `cpanel.example.com` and also colud login to my webmail using `webmail.example.com`. But recently, I have bought another cPanel **shared hosting** plan where I can't enter to those two address. Both `cpanel.example.com` and `webmail.example.com` says "server IP address could not be found." and also says "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN".

I have checked my cPanel's DNS Zone but there are no records of `cpanel.example.com` and `webmail.example.com`. And I think, the problem is with the DNS records.

Now, please tell me how to fix this problem. How can I use `cpanel.example.com` and `webmail.example.com` to login to cPanel and Webmail?

Answer (score 1):

For webmail.example.com I think you can open it as example.com:2096 and in case of cpanel.example.com you can open it with example.com:2083

These are the general settings for cpanel by default Still if you have any issue let me know

Comment: yes I am currently using this way. but it would be more neat and clean if I could use those subdomain

Comment: in fact, I had one with my previous hosting. I just can't remember what was the DNS records